# When printing to a Zebra printer from SSRS reports, resolution is really low and the lettering is fuzzy. How do I fix this?

Tags: reporting-services, printing, zebra-printers

When printing reports from SSRS to our Zebra printer the resolution is much worse and the lettering looks fuzzy.

This only happens when printing from SSRS to any Zebra printer. Printing from Crystal Reports works fine, as does printing to another printer such as a Xerox. If I print preview to a PDF viewer then print from there it is also fine.

I have tried updating the drivers, as well as downloading Seagull drivers but none of this helps.

I am printing from Epicor 10. And we are using SSRS version 2014.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of SSRS is it? The old 2008 R2 version has lots of printing issues. Also, which program/site are you printing from or are you using a custom report viewer control?

Comment: I am printing from Epicor 10. And we are using SSRS version 2014.